# Work with Assetic in Symfony bundle using sass compass and import image in scss file

Tags: symfony, sass, background-image, assetic, compass

I'm really impressed by how easy it is to use sass and compass in dev mode and generate the css in a single file when passing to production.

But like many on the web, I still have one problem. The import of the image inside the scss file like

```
#somedomid {
   background:url('../images/test.jpg');
}
```

I read all the questions, all the answers, I read also some really good tutorial on it but I begin to realize that there is only workaround and no one has a proper solution that :

- Use the symfony bundle (I can take the bundle as it and import it in another project -> no file in shared folder)
- Use assetic with the bundle path
- Import the image in css
- Have the same behaviour in dev and prod mode.

**For the moment I work with the following files :**

config.yml

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [MyBundle]
    ruby:           %ruby.bin%
    write_to:       %kernel.root_dir%/../web/
    ...
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        sass:
            bin:    %sass.bin%
        compass:
            bin:    %compass.bin%
    ...
```

And a twig like this :

```
{% stylesheets filter='compass' output='css/main.css'
    '@MyBundle/Resources/assets/sass/*.scss' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}"/>
{% endstylesheets %}
```

When I ask a page with app_dev.php the css is correctly generated and called
and when I deploy on server I make a assetic:dump and the css is perfectly generated and called too.

But even if I use cssrewrite filters, there is no way to get the image and I always get a 404 on :

```
app_dev.php/images/test.jpg
```

or

```
/Resources/assets/images/test.jpg (with cssrewrite)
```

**Where can I put this image in my bundle to be moved in execution time to the right folder ?**

Sorry for the long post and please, don't give me another workaround, I'm looking for the right solution.

Comment: Okey, I guess it's a bigger problem than I thought.